# How to find path to USB Disc Drive connected to USB 3.0 Bus in macOS Sierra 10.12.6?

Tags: terminal, usb, external-disk

We're running the SourceForge Freeware Utility known as DVD-A Author GUI (for Mac v19.06).  In short, it does everything it's supposed to do, except record the results to the external DVD writer connected to the USB 3.0 Bus. A Hitachi-LG Model No: SP80NB80.

This write function is known to work in the Windows environment, so we assume that it should work in macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra).  I have run the Terminal command "system_profiler SPUSBDataType" to verify that the external drive in question has been discovered by macOS, which it clearly has.

The present question is: how does one find the path to the same external USB drive so that we might "point" the freeware utility to it and, ultimately, have it write the program results as it was intended to?

Comment: What **specific** make and model of DVD writer? Also does the manufacturer offer Mac drivers? Usually standards compliant optical drives just work, with no drivers but there are exceptions, as you are finding...

Comment: @SteveChambers - The drive in question is a Hitachi-LG Model No: SP80NB80.  As the drive simply "worked" in both the Mac OS X 10.11.6 (past) and the macOS 10.12.6 (present) operating systems, we never really thought about adding extra drivers.  To clarify, the external drive in question functions when used in the macOS environment.  The freeware we're using -- which is identified in the original post -- is not "discovering" the drive, so, needless to say, we don't end up with the results we desire: a functioning DVD-A.  At this point, we would like to determine the path to the external drive.

Comment: If the Mac (and macOS) can use the drive to read and write CD/DVD discs then the issue is likely with the DVD Author app, **not** macOS. Your best bet would be to contact the developers. If it worked for previous versions of the app, can you revert to one of those versions?

Comment: @SteveChambers - There's no doubt that the issue is within the DVD-A Author GUI utility.  I have attempted to make contact with the developers, to no avail.  On the other hand, I did find a Read Me text file written by the main developer, and here's what he has to say about external drives: "If you want burn a disc with cdrecord [read: the patched utility that records DVDs], first check the 'Burn disc with cdrecord' [read: which we have] then enter a path in the line edit.  It will be kept in memory until changed."  The question remains: How do I determine the path to enter?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I can't help with that. Just a thought tho, can you create an ISO within the app and then burn **that** image to disk. Not ideal but perhaps a workaround till you get the issue properly resolved...

Comment: @SteveChambers - Okay, thanks for the thoughtful consideration and the replies.  As mentioned in the OP, we have a fully tested ISO image that has been burned to create a functioning DVD-A.  The problem is that it was burned via Windows - not macOS.  As we have had no luck finding a Mac burn utility that can handle multichannel audio ISO images, we reverted back to trying what the developer suggested: a line edit.  I'm not very experienced with macOS Terminal line edits; hence, the reason I came here.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SteveChambers - I just read your last response again...and, yes, burning the ISO image created by the DVD-A Author GUI utility -- from within the utility itself -- is what we wish to do, but, for whatever reason, the utility will not connect to our external DVD writer; hence, the questions about making a "line edit" using Terminal in macOS.